# simple kivy application not running on android?

Tags: kivy

i'm trying to run kivy examples on my android emulator, i can build them and install them on my device without any problem but i can't start them. does anybody have this problem too?
i'm using android API 18 as target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, I'm not clear...is your problem with an emulator or a device? Or you have different problems on each?

If it's an emulator, make sure you are using a recent android version (I think you need at least 4.1 or something), and it *must* have hardware acceleration enabled for kivy to work.

Either way, if the app installs but fails to start, that suggests something is crashing it at the initialisation stage. You should plug your device into your computer, enable adb in its developer options, and run `adb logcat` to see the device log in real time. Run your application, and you will see the initialisation log and any standard python log when the app fails. This should indicate the problem.

The adb tool comes with the android sdk, so you must have it if you built an apk, but you might need to find it manually somewhere in the sdk folder if it isn't already somewhere in your $PATH.

Answer (score 1):

You can run **adb logcat**, then try to start your app. After it crashes, you can ctrl+c to stop logcat and search for "died". Your error should be shown a few lines before it says your app died.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue in past and I solve by adding requirements in .spec

This requirements work for me:

```
requirements = hostpython3==3.7.8,python3==3.7.8,kivy==1.11.1, certifi,chardet, lxml, docutils, future, idna, Kivy-Garden, Pygments, requests, six, soupsieve, urllib3, deep-translator, arabic-reshaper, python-bidi, openssl, pyopenssl, numpy, pytz, python-dateutil, pandas, setuptools, zope.interface, datetime
```

you have to write all modules and parent module in requirements which your app is using.

To know module which you app is using has two method:

1. run command pip freeze in current app folder in powershell
2. install all the module as below photo which help to install your application module

[image]